# How to start a Celery worker from a script/module __main__?

Tags: python, celery, celeryd

I've define a `Celery` app in a module, and now I want to start the worker from the same module in its `__main__`, i.e. by running the module with `python -m` instead of `celery` from the command line. I tried this:

```
app = Celery('project', include=['project.tasks'])

# do all kind of project-specific configuration
# that should occur whenever this module is imported

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # log stuff about the configuration
    app.start(['worker', '-A', 'project.tasks'])
```

but now Celery thinks I'm running the worker without arguments:

```
Usage: worker <command> [options] 

Show help screen and exit.

Options:
  -A APP, --app=APP     app instance to use (e.g. module.attr_name)
[snip]
```

The usage message is the one you get from `celery --help`, as if it didn't get a command. I've also tried

```
app.worker_main(['-A', 'project.tasks'])
```

but that complains about the `-A` not being recognized.

So how do I do this? Or alternatively, how do I pass a callback to the worker to have it log information about its configuration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [code from Django-Celery module](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py) you could try something like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import current_app
from celery.bin import worker


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = current_app._get_current_object()

    worker = worker.worker(app=app)

    options = {
        'broker': 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
        'loglevel': 'INFO',
        'traceback': True,
    }

    worker.run(**options)
```

Comment: It looks like this is the deprecated way of starting the worker, but their new way is too tangled up in Django code for me to figure it out. I've gone with this solution, thanks.

Comment: Why deprecated? This code is run when you call `python manage.py celeryd`. It doesn't throw any warnings.

Comment: The code says it's the old way of running the worker.

Comment: Now I see it. Alternative solution has same concept. Take `djcelery/management/commands/celery.py` code and modify it, so it will always behave as `./manage.pu celery worker` is called.

Answer (score 24):

using app.worker_main method (v3.1.12):

```
± cat start_celery.py
#!/usr/bin/python

from myapp import app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = [
        'worker',
        '--loglevel=DEBUG',
    ]
    app.worker_main(argv)
```

Comment: Could you show what your myapp module contains? thanks

Comment: it was probably something like:

`
from celery import Celery
app = Celery()
`

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.worker_main

Comment: I get this error, AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute 'worker_main'.

Answer (score 20):

#### Since [Celery 5](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-5.0.html) things have been changed

The `worker_main` results now:

```
AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute 'worker_main'
```

#### For Celery 5 do following:

```py
app = celery.Celery(
    'project',
    include=['project.tasks']
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker = app.Worker(
        include=['project.tasks']
    )
    worker.start()
```

See here [celery.apps.worker](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.apps.worker.html#celery.apps.worker.Worker) and [celery.worker.WorkController.setup_defaults](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.worker.html#celery.worker.WorkController.setup_defaults) for details (hope it will be documented better in the future).

Comment: For anyone trying to do this in 2021 this is the approach that worked for me. (Celery version 5.1)

Comment: Nice, but can you reload the whoe thing? I tried worker.reload() it didn't work. Also tried worker.stop() and worker.start() but didn't work properly neither.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the worker is already running before initializing it and starting? Also, how do you specify what queue the worker should listen to with this method?

Comment: For specific queues, simply use the kwarg `queues` (e.g. `app.Worker(queues=["some_queue", "some_other_queue"])`). I still have not found a good way to see if a previously created worker process is still running on the host from within Python. Also, is there a way to call `worker.start()` without blocking?

Answer (score 10):

`worker_main` was put back in celery 5.0.3 here:
https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/6481

This worked for me on 5.0.4:

```py
self.app.worker_main(argv = ['worker', '--loglevel=info', '--concurrency={}'.format(os.environ['CELERY_CONCURRENCY']), '--without-gossip'])
```

Comment: Thanks x100 for this -- was trying to figure out how to start a celery worker from python instead of using the celery cli in the command line

Comment: How can you restart it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just missing wrapping the args so celery can read them, like:

```
queue = Celery('blah', include=['blah'])
queue.start(argv=['celery', 'worker', '-l', 'info'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand on [Tomasz Hławiczka's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075395/9403538) answer for Celery 5+. As mentioned in that answer, the following works:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery() # args and kwargs as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = app.Worker()
    worker.start()
```

However, I stumbled upon this answer while trying to run the Celery worker along side a Flask app with the Flask-SocketIO `run` method. Specifically, I tried to setup my worker, then run my flask app, however, `worker.start()` blocks, so the flask app never ran. To solve this, I used the following:

```
import subprocess
from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

cel = Celery() # args and kwargs as needed
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=<redis or rabbitmq here>)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd = "celery -A project.cel worker -Q specific_queue".split(' ')
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)

    socketio.run(app)
```

Or more generally:

```
import subprocess
from celery import Celery

app = Celery() # args and kwargs as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd = "celery -A project.app worker -Q specific_queue".split(' ')
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)

    # more code you need to run after starting worker
```

In addition, there are times previously created workers are still running, and you don't want to start more. This is particularly true during development. To check for other workers before starting another, you can do the following:

```
import subprocess
from celery import Celery

app = Celery() # args and kwargs as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    active_workers = app.control.inspect().active() 

    if active_workers == None:
        cmd = "celery -A project.app worker -Q specific_queue".split(' ')
        subprocess.Popen(cmd)

    # more code you need to run after starting worker
```

If you are doing all this across multiple hosts and you need to check for a specific worker, do the following:

```
import subprocess
from celery import Celery

app = Celery() # args and kwargs as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    active_workers = app.control.inspect().active() 

    if active_workers == None or "celery@hostname" not in active_workers.keys():
        cmd = "celery -A project.app worker -Q specific_queue".split(' ')
        subprocess.Popen(cmd)

    # more code you need to run after starting worker
```

If you don't care about blocking, and don't want to use the `subprocess` library but you still want your worker to listen to a specific queue, do the following:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery() # args and kwargs as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = app.Worker(queues=["specific_queue"])
    worker.start()
```

Of course, if you want multiple workers, each listening to their own specific queue, you'd have to use the subprocess method, as you cannot start another worker after the first `start()` call blocks.