# How to start a Celery worker in a [Python] script?

Tags: python, celery

I am looking for a Python only example on starting a Celery worker. I know there is the `celery worker` command line tool, but I would like to pass parameters to the app that the worker uses, and that seems to be complicated.

Is there no `app.startWorker(...)` method I can use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389104/how-to-start-a-celery-worker-from-a-script-module-main/23396197#23396197

Answer (score 2):

I think the best example would be the [celery worker code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/bin/worker.py).  This is what is called when you actually run the celery worker (wraps the worker classes). It looks pretty straightforward.