# upgrading celery 4.x.x to 5.x.x in Django app - execute_from_commandline() replacement

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

the usage in 4.x.x was as following:

```
from tenant_schemas_celery.app import CeleryApp

class TenantCeleryApp(CeleryApp):
    def create_task_cls(self):
        return self.subclass_with_self('...', abstract=True, name='...', attribute='_app')

tenant_celery = TenantCeleryApp()
base = celery.CeleryCommand(app=tenant_celery)
base.execute_from_commandline('...')
...
```

Now when updating celery lib to 5.x.x the following error show:

> ```
> base = celery.CeleryCommand(app=tenant_celery) 
> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app'
> ```

from the documentation, the new CeleryCommand use click.Command class, how do I change my code to fit - what is the replacement usage for **execute_from_commandline**()?

**EDIT:**
after some tries hard the following code works:

```
tenant_celery.worker_main(argv=['--broker=amqp://***:***@rabbitmq:5672//***',
                                    '-A', f'{__name__}:tenant_celery',
                                    'worker', '-c', '1', '-Q', 'c1,c2,c3,c4'])
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand the goal here.  Wouldn't you typically start celery from the command line using `celery multi` or `celery worker`?

Comment: its a legacy code where the worker starts via command line with script execution of python (in django).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a few things here.

---

The typical way to invoke / start a worker from within python [is discussed at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075395/6043170):

```py
worker = tenant_celery.Worker(
    include=['project.tasks']
)
worker.start()
```

In this case, you would be responsible for making the worker exit when you are done.

---

To execute the `CeleryCommand` / `click.Command`, you pass in the arguments to the `main` function

```
base = CeleryCommand()
base.main(args=['worker', '-A', f'{__name__}:tenant_celery'])
```

You would still be responsible for controlling how celery exits in this case, too.  You may choose a verb other than `worker` such as `multi` for whatever celery subcommand you were expecting to call.

You may also want to explicitly specify the [name of the celery module for the `-A` parameter as discussed here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/next-steps.html#about-the-app-argument).

Comment: when trying to use CeleryCommand.main like shown it throws ex: TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.  When adding 'self' the following exception appears: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute '_main_shell_completion'.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, please see the update.

Comment: tried:
base = celery.CeleryCommand(name='test')
base.main(args=['worker', '-A', f'{__name__}:tenant_celery'])

got:
self.ctx.obj.error(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'

and why it has to have "name" in the base object?

Comment: also, what is the difference from your suggestion to use:
        tenant_celery.worker_main(argv=['worker', '-A', f'{__name__}:tenant_celery'])
?